# Delete 2 lines of text before the line containing the matching pattern using sed?

Tags: awk, sed, grep, tac

I have a file containing the following lines:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
pattern
eee
fff
ggg
pattern
hhh
```

I would like to delete 2 lines before the last matching `pattern` in the file. The expected output is:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
pattern
eee
pattern
hhh
```

I tried -
`sed -i '/pattern/{N;N;d;}' file`
but it didn't work. There was no change to the file.

I also tried -
`tac file | sed '/pattern/,+2 d' | tac > tmpfile && mv tmpfile file`
but this also deleted the line containing the matching pattern.

My sed version is `sed (GNU sed) 4.7`.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If your first command didn't change the file, it means the pattern didn't match. Had it matched it would have deleted 3 lines (none of them being the ones you wanted deleted).

Comment: how large is the file?

Comment: I tried adding 4 lines to the file `temp.txt` - ```aaa bbb ccc ddd``` on each line and then ran `sed -i '/ccc/{N;N;d;}' temp.txt`. The file was as is after running the command. The file is around 350K. It contains 6500 lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sed` is the wrong tool for this. Any time you want to **ed**it a file, especially if you want to look backwards after some matching bit, `ed` is almost always a better option, as it's designed to work with files, not a stream of lines always moving forward.

```bash
ed -s file.txt <<'EOF'
?pattern?-2;+1 d
w
EOF
```

or if a heredoc isn't convenient

```bash
printf '%s\n' '?pattern?-2;+1 d' w | ed -s file.txt
```

will first set the current line to the one two before the *last* one matching `pattern`, and then **d**elete that line and the one following (So the two lines preceding that last match of `pattern`), and finally **w**rite the modified file back out.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to run this command in a single line?

Comment: `printf '?pattern?-2;+ d\nw\n' | ed -s file.txt`

Comment: @jhnc I'd use `printf '%s\n' '?pattern?-2;+1 d' w | ed -s file.txt` to make the different commands more clear.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** HatLess's `sed` solution looks much better to me.

I agree with the Shawn's answer; `sed` is not the best tool for the job. But here's a solution with `sed`:

Have a `script.sed` file:

```
# read the full file into the pattern space
:1
$! { N ; b1 }

# replace last occurrence of "2 lines plus pattern line"
# with just the pattern line
s/(.*\n.*\n)(pattern\n?.*)\'/\2/m
```

Run it like this:

```bash
sed -E -f script.sed file.txt
```

Or in a single line like this:

```bash
sed -E ':1 ; $! { N ; b1 } ; s/(.*\n.*\n)(pattern\n?.*)\'\''/\2/m' text
```

The basic idea is that, because we need to work on the latest pattern in the file, we need to read the entire file before modifying it.

The first two lines are a loop using `sed`'s goto-like commands:

- `:1` creates a label called `1`.
- `$!` makes sure that we run the following commands for every line except the last one.

  - `N` reads the next line.
  - `b1` jumps to the label `1`.

The following substitution command will only run on the last line. Note the following:

- We don't need to escape the capturing group parentheses (`\(` and `\)`) because we call sed with the `-E` flag which turns on the Extended Regular Expression syntax.
- We pass the flag `m` to the substitute command, which makes the regex work in multiline mode. In our case, this provides the following characteristics:

  - The dot (`.`) no longer matches newline characters (`\n`). This is useful in our case because we want to be explicit about the number of lines we match.
  - It enables the special `\'` character (a `sed`-only feature), which matches the end of the buffer. We need this to anchor our regex to the end of the file.
- Also note the `\n?` after pattern. Because `sed` reads lines without the trailing new line, this is a way to match a "pattern" that might be either the last line or a line in the middle of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU `sed`

```
$ sed -Ezi.bak 's/(.*\n)([^\n]*\n){2}(pattern)/\1\3/' input_file
aaa
bbb
ccc
pattern
eee
pattern
hhh
```

Answer (score 0):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
pattern
eee
fff
ggg
pattern
hhh
```

then

```
awk '{arr[NR]=$0}/pattern/{ln=NR}END{for(i=1;i<=NR;i+=1){if(i+2!=ln&&i+1!=ln){print arr[i]}}}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
pattern
eee
pattern
hhh
```

Explanation: I store lines of `file.txt` in array `arr` with keys being their numbers, if `pattern` found I set `ln` variable to line of number. After all lines are stores I iterate over `arr` `print` lines whose numbers are not `ln` less 1 and `ln` less 2.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -En ':a
         N
         /(.*(pattern))\n?(.*\2)/{h;s//\1/p;x;s//\3/}
         ${s/([^\n]*\n){2}(pattern)/\2/;p}
         ba' file
```

Gather up the lines of the file.

If the collection contains two occurrences of the `pattern`, print upto and including the first `pattern`, then reduce the current collection by the same amount (minus an introduced leading newline).

At the end of the file, match on `pattern` again, this time removing the two lines before it and print the result.

Alternative:

```
sed -zE 's/(.*)(\n[^\n]*){2}(\npattern)/\1\3/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

**tac + sed**

```
tac infile | sed -n '
    p
    /pattern/ {
        n
        n
    :a
        n
        p
        ba
    }
' | tac >tmpfile &&
mv tmpfile infile
```

**sed + shell**

```
(
    n=$(sed -n '/pattern/=' infile | tail -n 1)
    sed -i "$((n-2)),$((n-1))d" infile
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using any `awk` with `tac` and only reading 1 line at a time into memory:

```
$ tac file | awk '!(c && c--); !f && /pattern/{f=c=2}' | tac
aaa
bbb
ccc
pattern
eee
pattern
hhh
```

Most of the other posted solutions are reading the whole input into memory and so will fail if the input is too large to fit in memory.

Comment: However `| tac` snarfs everything into a temporary file and then invokes its algorithm for reversing a file.  I think the ideal approach here in terms of resources would be to make two passes over the file: one to identify where the unwanted lines occur and then another to filter them out by position.

Comment: @Kaz ah, that makes sense, thanks. Still avoids the potential memory issue of course but you're right it'd introduce a disk space one.

Answer (score 0):

We can avoid using temporary files (e.g. via `tac`) or loading the file into RAM, or editing in-place, if we make two passes over it:

```
$ awk 'NR == FNR && /pattern/ { pos = NR }
       NR == FNR { next }
       FNR < pos - 2 || FNR >= pos' data data
aaa
bbb
ccc
pattern
eee
pattern
hhh
```

Here, I'm giving the `data` file twice as an argument on awk's command line. The condition `NR == FNR` is an idiom in awk which evaluates to true when we are processing the first file (thus, in our case, the first pass over the same file).

In the first pass, we record the line number of the last line which matches `pattern`, simply by recording the position of line which matches pattern into the same `pos` variable.

In the second pass through the data, we print all lines which are not one of the two lines before `pos`.

Comment: When Bulter Lampson said that all problems in computer science can be solved by adding another layer of indirection, he totally forgot about the power of adding another pass. :)

Comment: The issue with that is it wouldn't work if the input was coming from a pipe rather than a file BUT the OP did say "I have a file..." so it's probably OK for them and anyone can always create a temp file to work on if necessary (assuming enough disk space).